# How many connections can you have off of CPVC

Tags: plumbing, cpvc

I am looking to add a wet bar to my bathroom and was looking to tap into my CPVC lines to provide the water.   Currently there are some 1/2" lines running near where I want to go that tap off of a 3/4" trunk.  Some plumbers that I had in were saying that we couldn't use the 1/2" lines as there'd be too many tap offs from the line, which leads to my question - How many connections can you have off of 1/2 and 3/4" CPVC?  I tried doing some googling, but the best I can find talks about what the max pressure for each size is, which doesn't mean much to me.  FWIW, this would be residential, schedule 40 piping.

Comment: Google WSFU (water supply fixture units) or use the above link. See here for [drainage fixture units: DFU](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30510/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-connections-to-pipes)

Comment: I'm confused.  That DFU link is talking about drainage.  I'm talking about water supply lines.  And is there a difference between limits on copper vs CPVC?

Comment: I think @Mazura appropriately included the drainage fixture units with the presumption that installation of a wet bar with a faucet would also require an additional drain.

Comment: The ID of copper pipe is negligibly smaller than CPVC. But both of those suffer severely from every Tee, elbow and valve. You have to go to PEX to avoid most of those reductions. - Whatever new work is being done, assuming it's local to one room, can be done in 1\2" anything (caveat: dielectrics), and then feed later with 3/4" if the flow is unacceptable.

Comment: So right now I have 1/2" branch that is feeding a toilet and sink.  Ideally, I'd like to T that connection and add a bar sink and possibly a dishwasher.

Comment: Anecdotally, I used to have a 3/4" run to my shower, which went on to the kitchen. It literally took two minuets to warm up, and you still knew when the kitchen sink or the DW was running. Code tables-*smables*: If I had to re-do that today, it'd be a half inch homerun to the bathroom and a 3/4" to the kitchen.

Comment: No shower or tub? Half inch all day.

Comment: I'm curious, was this a suggestion, or did they outright refuse the piddly job of installing a Tee and a valve? ;p - That, you should be able to do yourself no problem, in mere hours, not *days* that a new run would entail.