# what is the correct slope for a 2" horizontal drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, drains

For a 2" drain pipe horizontal run in a bathroom, what is the correct slope drop per 10 feet?

Also, can a single 2" drain pipe support a separate tub, shower and 2 sinks?

Answer (score 1):

1/4 inch per foot is most common and is the minimum allowed. Maximum allowed is 3 inches per foot

So on a 10 foot section that would be 2.5 inches total slope minimum and 30 inches maximum.

For the second part of your question see the answer to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30510/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-connections-to-pipes).